# Skaffold dev stops watching for changes and logs from pods are not generated anymore

Tags: skaffold

I have successfully managed to setup (besides my issue) Skaffold for our project.

I am using K3D as local kubernetes platform & a local registry in K3

It consists of two .NET core projects in which one of them is using a third one (.dll)
Because of this the two docker files are situated in different paths.

It starts as expected and runs despite i might have some issues with how the Images are handled.

But out of a sudden, intermittently i get :

[image]

and skaffold wont display log output or do anything more.
I can still access the services and everything works within and if i run kubectl logs  i can see the logs.

For the record, i am using windows, WSL2, Docker is on the windows "side" and Skaffold runs within Linux.

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta15
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: vcc.spr
build:
  #tagPolicy:
  #  sha256: {}
  local:
    concurrency: 0
    tryImportMissing: true
  artifacts:
  - image: k3d-spr-registry:12345/coreodata
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_odata
  - image: k3d-spr-registry:12345/corepoint
    context: VCC.SPR.CorePoint
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  insecureRegistries:
  - k3d-spr-registry:12345
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    #- k8s/configmap/configmap.yaml
    - k8s/deployment/coreodata.yaml
    - k8s/deployment/corepoint.yaml
    - k8s/ingress/spr-ingress.yaml
    #- k8s/namespace/SPR_namespace.yaml
    - k8s/networkpolicy/networkpolicy.yaml
    #- k8s/secrets/localsecret.yaml
    - k8s/service/coreodata.yaml
    - k8s/service/corepoint.yaml
    #defaultNamespace: skaffolddev
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer to this issue myself, it was because i had my code/repo in a windows (ntfs) folder and ran from a wsl2 (linux) client.
Obviously its not a great solution at the moment, more on this can be read here :
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/docker-desktop-on-wsl2-the-problem-with-mixing-file-systems-a8b5dcd79b22

Comment: Skaffold supports other file-change detection mechanisms with `--trigger` including `polling` (see `--watch-poll-interval` for altering the time between checks) or `manual` where you need to hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to check for changes.

Comment: thanks for the answer! yes we saw that too but i would think the problem with having the project in the ntfs-filesystem would still be a problem.
However, we also need to be able to trigger manually since the build takes some time at the moment so that is valuable information.